# Different sessions for different tabs of the same browser

Tags: java, session

I am using timestamp till nano second as a user session, say tab A has session1 and user opens tab B say this session is session2 and now session1 gets only inactivated after some file upload activity is done at this point of time I want the session2 be still active.

How do I do this without using cookies?

Comment: How do you manage the sessions? Do you use cookies?

Comment: Oops my fault. Changed my question. I am not using cookies.

Comment: Well, what *do* you use to manage sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you looked into html5 `sessionStorage`/`localStorage` ?

these apis sport a client-side storage facility pretty similar to cookies which you can employ to manage sessions. the lifetime of the database is either the lifetime of the respective tab/window (ssessionStorage) or the interval between two consecutive deletions the pertaining browser data; the latter may depend on the browser preferences (eg. automatically after closing the tab/window in privacy mode or upon express user request).

for a start, [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) has something to say about it. there also is [a full-fledged tutorial on html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/).

the gritty in-depth [w3c standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) details all about the programmatic (javascript) interface.

the api do not provide facilities to exchange information between client and server. one option to handle this part would be encoding the information into urls (client -> server) or http headers (server -> client) being called/received through ajax.

a final word of warning: for security reasons, **do not store authenticating data this way**.

Answer (score 0):

> say tab A has session1 and user opens tab B say this session is session2

This is already impossible. Both tabs will be in the same session. If tab B created a new session due to a login for example, tab A will now be in the new session.

> and now session1 gets only inactivated after some file upload activity

It won't happen.

> is done at this point of time I want the session2 be still active.

It still is. Session 1 will have been destroyed if it's different from session 2.

Comment: whether the op's scenario is possible or not depends on what a 'session' means.

Comment: It means an HTTP session. It can't really mean anything else.

Comment: what is a 'http session'? http is a stateless protocol, so the session concept cannot be mapped without additional facilities.